# How is this done? Scrolling downwards = slick slideshow (on Google Cardboard website)

Tags: css, html, scroll

Take a look at https://developers.google.com/cardboard/ or https://gweb-cardboard.appspot.com/ to see what I'm talking about.

I love this new, super-simple scrolling functionality: I think it's so smooth, intuitive and slick. But I can't work out how it's done by inspecting elements, etc. Can anyone explain what's going on here and how complex it is?

Comment: I guess for every scroll the image src changes.

Comment: https://github.com/janpaepke/ScrollMagic is the plugin - I think it uses the `pin` functionality, and then on scroll it just sets the next item (based on the index) to be visible. Simple pinning example demo - http://janpaepke.github.io/ScrollMagic/examples/basic/simple_pinning.html

Comment: Just look at the source
`<img src="img/seq/01.jpg" />
<img src="img/seq/02.jpg" /> ...` Also this kind of question is not suitable for SO.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know this wasn't the right place to ask this question. But thanks also for the bits of advice.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty complex :P Especially considering they need an image for each frame.  The overall concept is definitely not unique check out Sony's version: http://discover.store.sony.com/be-moved/  It's called Parallax scrolling, sorta.